# Referencing buttons with numbers

Tags: c#, button

Is there a way to reference buttons using a numerical value in C#?  I am trying to manipulate the text on buttons using one reusable method.  Here is my current coding:
One button click method (there are a total of 16):

```
private void Card1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buff = CardClick(1);
        if (buff != null)
        {
            Card1.Text = buff;
        }
    }
```

And the reusable method (the code does have holes, it's in development):

```
private string CardClick(int card)
        {
            guesses[g++] = card;  //alternate g
            if ((guesses[0] != null) && (guesses[1] != null))
            {
                //Reset Card guesses[0]
                //Reset Card guesses[1]
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (card > 8)
                {
                    return map[2, card];
                }
                else
                {
                    return map[1, card];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you in Forms? Wpf? XAML? ASP.Net? WinRT? Windows Phone?... The answer is 42. :)

Comment: Question is unclear at the moment. Provide more info

Comment: Your Question is not clear,add some more details what are you trying to do and what have you done so far?

Comment: I am using windows forms

Comment: still that is not enough information,share your code with some details about what are you trying to do..

Comment: @Fearless Jerry gave us a nice idea maintaining your buttons in a array. Take a look at his post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Controls.Find() to get a reference to your desired button based on its name:

```
        int i = 1;
        Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find("Card" + i.ToString(), true);
        if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is Button)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)matches[0];
            // ... do something with "btn" ...
            btn.PerformClick();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of buttons

```
   Button[] buttonArray = new Button[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the buttons from your form by Type and then extract an array:

```
public Button[] AllButtons()
    {
        var buttons = new List<Button>();

        foreach (var control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                buttons.Add((Button)control);
        }

        return buttons.ToArray();
    }
```