# Access object without knowing the name beforehand

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I access an object without knowing its name ? (how to concatenate object name).
I have the following code:

```
    private void pb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Check("1");
    }


    void Check(string x)
    {   
            if (("pb"+x).Image == img1)
            {
                ("pb"+x).Image = img2;                    
            }            
    }
```

Comment: whats wrong with the `sender` object provided?  But that will not compare images.

Comment: No, you cannot do this. Whenever you attach numbers to your variables, that's a clear signal that you should be using a container, like a List or Array instead.

Comment: Form controls are already in a collection so if you really must use a lookup name; `var pb = (PictureBox)this.Controls.Find("pb" + x, false).FirstOrDefault();` Also to remind comparing images like that is for reference equality.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469894/referencing-buttons-with-numbers/19470283#19470283) for another example of `Controls.Find ()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pass the controls' name. You'll be better off by passing a reference to that object, which you already have in the eventhandler:

```
private void pb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SwapImages(sender as PictureBox);
}

private void SwapImages(PictureBox pb)
{   
    if (pb.Image == img1)
    {
        pb.Image = img2;                    
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to go about it.  I would recommend you use a dictionary to keep track of your loaded objects, and then just look them up by number in the dictionary.

```
private Dictionary<int, MyClass> myDict = new Dictionary<int, MyClass>();

void Check(int value)
{
    MyClass target = null;
    myDict.TryGetValue(value, out target);
    //target.Image = etc.
}
```